# Display inline não funciona corretamente com span

Tags: jsf, xhtml

Meu `display:inline` não funcionar corretamente gostaria de saber onde estou errando ele devera ficar parecido com este aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem não consigo segue meu código abaixo:

```css
.abertura-chamados li {
  display: inline;
}
.abertura-chamados li a img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="abertura-chamados">
  <li>
    <p:commandLink>
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/4/47/Riot_Games_logo.png" /><span>Abertura de chamados manutenção</span>
    </p:commandLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p:commandLink>
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/4/47/Riot_Games_logo.png" /><span>Prisma Sisteplant</span>
    </p:commandLink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Obs: Estou usando XHTML ou seja as imagens estão setadas com a *tag* `<h:graphicImage name="..." library="images">`
não conseguir adicionar as imagens com essa *tag* não sei porque por isso ultilizei a `<img>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é porque quando a resolução do ecrã é demasiado pequena, a lista - também conhecida como `li` vai automaticamente ser partida em várias linhas porque a imagem e/ou a `li` são demasiado grandes para caber no ecrã, a menos que existisse um `parent` cujo a `width` esteja definida ou fosse maior do que a atual largura do ecrã, por exemplo:

```css
.container {width:1000px;}
.abertura-chamados li {display: inline;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="abertura-chamados">
    <li>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/4/47/Riot_Games_logo.png" /><span>Abertura de chamados manutenção</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/4/47/Riot_Games_logo.png" /><span>Prisma Sisteplant</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

No exemplo acima não conseguimos ter as imagens `"inline"` porque a `li` e a `img` são demasiado grandes porque nós não especificamos nenhuns parâmetros para as suas larguras e alturas, e porque o seu `parent` não tem uma largura definida e a sua largura padrão será de `width:100%;`. Mas se nós o fizessemos elas seriam apresentadas algo parecido como neste exemplo abaixo: http://jsfiddle.net/fmsq5k1x/

```css
.abertura-chamados li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    max-width: 130px;
}
.abertura-chamados li img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="abertura-chamados">
    <li>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/4/47/Riot_Games_logo.png" /><span>Abertura de chamados manutenção</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/4/47/Riot_Games_logo.png" /><span>Prisma Sisteplant</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Qualquer das maneiras ela irá sempre ser partida em várias linhas a menos que tenhamos uma div `parent` com uma largura especificada como por exemplo: `width:700px;` como já referi anteriormente. Mas nós sempre podemos adiar o seu "partimento" como no exemplo acima ou usando media queries etc.

Comment: muito boa a explicação e facil de entender a resolução muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda =3

Comment: De nada @Kirito , boa continuação de encriptação ;)